# Is there a way to determine how often Chrony is querying NTP servers to sync time?

Tags: ntp, time-synchronization, chrony

Is there any way to tell how often Chrony is querying NTP servers?

If the answer is that it uses some algorithm based on how much the server has been out of sync in the past, is there some documentation on how that algorithm works?

Is there a way to set a minimum time frame for the query frequency?

Answer (score 1):

To set the minimum time frame in Chrony
`nano /etc/chrony.conf`
after your server add 
**maxpoll** *poll*
This option specifies the maximum interval between requests sent to the server as a power of 2 in seconds.

Example:
`server 0.europe.pool.ntp.org maxpoll 8`
This will force Chrony to sync every 256 seconds

Answer (score 0):

To check how many seconds has passed since last sync:

```
$ chronyc sources
```

Look the column 'LastRx'

To set a minimum time frame to sync, use the 'minpoll' option in the /etc/chrony.conf file.

```
server 0.centos.pool.ntp.org minpoll 10
```

Comment: I believe you actually want `maxpoll`.  `minpoll` is the *shortest* amount of time allowed between polls; whereas, `maxpoll` is the *longest* amount of time possible.  You'd want a smaller `maxpoll` to check the servers more often.

From https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/s1-Configure_NTP.html#s2_Configuring_the_Poll_Interval - "Setting a shorter maxpoll may improve clock accuracy."

Comment: @abegosum any idea why a shorter maxpoll may improve the clock accuracy?